How to add new tailwind property class?
I am working on an app using tailwind,
I want to add the image-rendering: pixelated class to a canvas element but I couldn't find how to do it in tailwind
I tried looking for image rendering tailwind classes but could not find any, Looking at the tailwind config documentation I only found how to implement this by creating a custom class for any image-rendering value possible
I would appreciate if you could help me implement a custom rendering-[render type] tailwind class which can be extended in the config file

You can use matchUtilities to create a utility class that accepts arbitrary values for image-rendering:
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ matchUtilities }) {
      matchUtilities({
        rendering: (value) => ({
          'image-rendering': value,
        }),
      })
    }),
  ],
}

Now this:
<div class="rendering-[pixelated]"></div>

Generates the following CSS rule:
.rendering-\[pixelated\] {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

Playground

Note that you can also use the custom property syntax for this if you don't want to reuse this too many times:
<div class="[image-rendering:pixelated]"></div>

generates:
.\[image-rendering\:pixelated\] {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

